# Multiple Textbox in a window WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Iam creating this project which uses on screen keyboard. The problem is I have several textboxes in my window. The question is, when I selected the textbox and start using the on screen keyboard, the text should be displayed on the textbox that I selected.

there will be a possibility that not all the textbox are being used depending on the user's preference.

Here's my sample code when I click the button

```
private void button_numeric_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{

       if (txtThousand.Focus())
        {

            txtThousand.Text += "1";
            // txtThousand.Focus();
            txtThousand.SelectionStart = txtThousand.Text.Length;

        }
        else  if (txtFivehundred.Focus())
        {

            txtFivehundred.Text += "1";
            txtFivehundred.Focus();
            txtFivehundred.SelectionStart = txtThousand.Text.Length;

        }
    }
```

My problem now is how can I determine which text box is active.

When I used this code:

```
private void StartKeyBoardProcess(TextBox tb)   
{
        try
        {
            if (tb != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pumasok!");
                tb.Focus();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
}

private void txtThousand_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    StartKeyBoardProcess(tb);
}
```

Nothing happens.

When I Click my button, It only input text in the First Textbox. When I click the other textbox, It continue inputting in the first text box.

Can anyone tell me how to work this out? I'm so new with WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is the simple solution. You call your method with the textbox you clicked on etc. and start the process and force focus to the texbox you touched.

```
 private void StartKeyBoardProcess(Textbox tb) {
    try {
      if (tb != null) {
          Process.Start("osk.exe", "/C");
          tb.Focus();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      Messagebox.Show("Error: StartKeyBoardProcess: "+ex);
    }
  }

 private void TextBox_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
   Textbox tb = sender as Textbox;
   StartKeyBoardProcess(tb);
 }
```

Something like this :)

Comment: What is the event for Textbox Click in WPF?

Comment: I use "MouseLeftButtonUp" which registers the same way as a "Click" event does.

Comment: So Ill call the function you've given me in my "MouseLeftButtonUp" event? Sorry Im so new with wpf.

Comment: I'll write the other function aswell up in my answer. :) everyone has been new at some point

Comment: Still not working. I'll give you my source code. Tell me what's wrong.

Comment: I have a really hard time figuring out what exactly you want to do. You click a button, and then it checks weather one of them has focus, the one that has focus (btw. use Textbox.isfocused for your checks, the other way around you set the focus instead of checking). and then you wanna add some text to the focused textbox :P Is that correct?

Comment: I've figure out this one! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event:

```
private void txtThousand_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    StartKeyBoardProcess(tb);
}
```